# Issue compiling Vulkan API samples on Android N

Tags: android, compiler-errors, runtime-error, gpu, vulkan

I am attempting to run vulkan API samples on Android N.I am currently facing an issue  .I am able to compile the samples provided by LunarG (https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/tree/master/API-Samples )  and generate apk,but at runtime physical devices accessible to a Vulkan instance is being returned as invalid value.So the app crashes
Any suggestions on how to proceed further.

Comment: What device are you running the examples on? There are only a few Android devices supporting Vulkan right now (it's not sufficent if the device support Android N). If the physical device can't be created then the device doesn't support Vulkan (yet).

Comment: Agreed with Sascha, we need a few more details.  Devices, platform, anything you can tell us about how you're running the API, etc...

Comment: I am running the examples on Nexus 6 which has been flashed with Android N developer Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am running the examples on Nexus 6 which has been flashed with Android N developer Preview

The Nexus 6 doesn't support Vulkan (yet), there are no drivers for it's Adreno 420 GPU.

Afaik the only Nexus devices that support Vulkan (as of now) are the Nexus 6P (Adreno 430, see [Vulkan report here](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=283)) and the Nexus player.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started.html, there's the Nexus 5X also.

Comment: Is the Adreno 420 actually capable of Vulkan, or is the lack of support due to a lack of drivers?

Comment: [Comparing those two](http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/gles_comparereports.php?reports_length=50&776=1&747=1) they're pretty much a match, so I'm sure it's only down to the drivers. From what I can tell the only difference between these two is in performance. In terms of features, the 420 should have anything required for Vulkan, especially as the (http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=282)[418] can run Vulkan. But in the end the choice of drivers is down to the device vendor.